# Comment to tell Closure Compiler / Linter to ignore specific lines

Tags: javascript, jslint, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

What's the comment you use to tell Closure Compiler / Linter to ignore specific lines?  I remember it was something like:

```
var x = "some line that is too big"; /** CLOSURE_IGNORE E0101 */
```

That's not the exact syntax. I can't find it on Google, ironically... anyone know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell the closure compiler to ignore code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685998/how-do-i-tell-the-closure-compiler-to-ignore-code)

Comment: which the compiler or the linter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `goog.DEBUG` flag. A good description of its use can be found in [Closure: The Definitive Guide](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449381882/additional-utilities/id3158590).

Let's say you have code that looks like this:

```
var foo = 'bar';
if (goog.DEBUG) {
    doDebugOnlyWork();
}
var fizz = 'buzz';
```

When this gets compiled, the compiler will remove the code within the `goog.DEBUG` branch. Obfuscations and optimizations aside, that will result in the functional equivalent of this:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var fizz = 'buzz';
```

Comment: Not quite. This is for debug only code. I am saying that I want the code to run, but I don't want it to get flagged as hitting a specific error (typically "Line too long")  There is a way to do this with a comment.

Comment: Ah. The closest thing I can think of is `@suppress`, but that's for warnings, not for errors. https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings

Comment: [`@suppress` docs now on GitHub.](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings)